# Prerender components in react to prevent content jumping?

Tags: reactjs

I have a slider component in react that you press a button and it displays a different component (basically power point slides with some user input).

The problem is the images are loaded once the component is displayed so there is some popping as the images load on slow connections.

Is there anyway to easily prerender the next component to prevent this popping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you create a state named `isLoading` and set it to `true` at first:

```
state = {
  isLoading: true,
  // the other states
}
```

When `isLoading === true`, just render an empty `div`, or a `Loader` if you use SemanticUI. And when the loading completes, just set it to `false` and render your content. Something like below:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    // the other states
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    loadImageFunction().then() // Whatever you want to do
    .then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <div></div>;
    }
    return <div>Your images go in here...</div>;
  }
}
```

Hope this idea help solve your question.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to easily preload a component though? Since we are slide 1 we know slide 2 is likely to come up, I'm not sure if react has some way to prerender so it could load images in the background?

I like your solution though!